# JS - how to prevent script from stopping after thrown error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I prevent the script from stopping after an error has been thrown? Is there something like exception handling in JS?

Console text

```
 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/Temp/image.png
```

Comment: Add the code that throws the error to your question.

Comment: try/catch usually works, like you'd expect, but there are some errors which you can't catch because they are triggered by other events (e.g. when loading a bad resource as in your example, the error is only known about after the javascript part has finished executing). But in those cases, it won't stop the script anyway (it just logs a warning which you can't avoid).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript does have exception handling. There are two possible types of error you can encounter:

1) Places in your application where you proactively guard against errors being thrown, for example, AJAX request. You can handle them like this:

```
try {
  AJAX-code or other code susceptible to errors
} catch(error){
  // Log error 
}
```

2) Script errors or compile-time error, for example, undefined variables. In browsers, [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror) is a global event handler which is called on script or compile errors. However, it's implementation is inconsistent across browsers. You can use it like this:

```
window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNo) {
   // Code to handle the error
}
```

The main problem with onerror is that no stack trace is passed through which is not very helpful. However, Chromium has added column number and errorObj, so hopefully other browsers will implement the same in near future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `try`/`catch`/`finally` block to handle errors:

```
try {
  // Whatever you need
} catch(error) {
  // Handle error if one occurs
} finally {
  // Last resort
}
```

Note that you can have multiple `catch` blocks in-between your `try` and `finally` as needed.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)'s some more information.

Answer (score 0):

There surely is: `try {} catch (exception) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, wrap your code inside try/catch:

```
try
{
  //Run some code here
}
catch(err)
{
 //Handle errors here
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch